# upload progress with post processing

Tags: php, jquery, css, html

I have an upload form where users can upload files. After the upload is done the files are post processed and sometimes the processing takes up to 10-15 seconds after the upload has completed..

After the upload is done the progress bar is at 100%, but how is it possible to detect when the file has completed, so you could show the user a "please wait" sign while the file is processing.. The user might think that the browser has frozen og crashed since the progress bar is at 100% but nothing is happening..

A client-side solution in pure HTML5+javascript is preferred, but not a must :)

Comment: Maybe a second progress bar for the post process ?

Comment: If you want to control all the aspects of the upload, like you want to know how much is uploaded, how much to be uploaded etc, you could take a look at http://www.resumablejs.com/ . This js library allows you to even resume the uploads. This gives complete control of uploads to you. But there is a little problem, you need to do some configs in the backend also. And after the upload, you could either poll using ajax or use node.js to display live progress of what is happening in the backend.

Comment: If you are using PHP as the server scripting then better to make use of APC module. Using this you can update the progress asynchronously.

Comment: Could you please make the processing part a bit more clear. I don't see any code samples and cannot guess how you handle the upload.

Answer (score 7):

Try

html

```
<progress min="0" max="10000"></progress>
<output for="progress"></output>
<output for="progress"></output>
<br />
<table id="results"></table>
```

js

```
var len = arr.length // file length
    , start = 0 // update progress
    , outputs = $("output[for=progress]") // notifications
    , progress = $("progress")
    , results = $("#results") // post processing 
    // gif spinner
    , spinner = $("<img />", {
    "src": "data:image/gif;charset=binary;base64,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"
});
// upload file
var request = function () {
    progress.prop("max", len);
    s = setInterval(function () {
        progress.prop("value", ++start);
        outputs.eq(0)
            .text("uploading file...")
    }, 1)
    return $.post("/echo/json/", {
        json: JSON.stringify(arr)
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        clearInterval(s)
        s = null;
        progress.prop("value", len);
        outputs.eq(0)
            .html("upload complete ! <br />processing response, please wait...")
        .next(outputs.eq(1))
        .html(spinner);
        return data
    })
};

request()
.then(function (data) {
    // do post upload processing stuff
    var process = function() {
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();
    // processing...
    t = setTimeout(function () {
        data.forEach(function (res) {
            results.append(
            $("<tr />", {
                "html": $("<td />", {
                    "html": res.value
                })
            }))
        });
        if (results.find("tr").length === len) {
           dfd.resolve("complete !")
        }
    }, 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 15000));
        return dfd.promise()
    };
    // do stuff when all post processing complete
    process().then(function(complete) {
       outputs.eq(0).empty()
       .next(outputs.eq(1))
       .html(complete);
       clearTimeout(t);
       t = null;
    })
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/d2szrs20/

Comment: Im trying to figure out your code.. but isn't `.then()` on jquery ajax requests (promise) first triggered when the HTTP request completes?

Comment: @clarkk You are correct . The first `then` , within `request` returns response to second `then` , where `process` returns a `promise` within second `then` . There are three `.then` calls ; 1) process file upload , set `progress` based on `file` `length` , returns response to second `.then` ; 2) process response from `$.ajax` , after possible 10-15 second delay from request ; 3) complete `progress` processing . At actual `file` upload , `arr.length` would be `files[0].size` .  Variable `setTimeout` portion included to simulate "10-15 second delay" described at OP .

Answer (score 5):

Since you have progress bar to show form process **To add more detail while from processing you can add image like bellow**

It will display user that your form is still on process [create your custom image here](http://www.ajaxload.info/)

[image]

This might help user - browser has not frozen.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a custom upload widget for this. On the server side, I send the following information to the client when it requests an update: Percentage of the file received plus a status message. Via the message, I can give additional feedback like which step of the post processing is happening or display errors.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a jquery plugin called pekeupload 
It is small and easy to implement and customize

http://plugins.jquery.com/pekeUpload/
https://github.com/pekebyte/pekeUpload

I hope that this help you

best

Answer (score 2):

Javascript

```
function initialize_progress(element)
{
    //initializations!
    $(element).hide();
    $(element).find('.progress-bar').prop('style','width: 0');
}


function getProgress(process_id){
    var re=new RegExp(process_id+"=[^;]+", "i") //construct RE to search for target name/value pair
    if (document.cookie.match(re)) //if cookie found
        return document.cookie.match(re)[0].split("=")[1] //return its value
    return null
}


function updateProgress(process_id, element){

    var percentage, message, name, failed;


    $(element).show();
    var myIntervalID = setInterval(function()
    {
        percentage = getProgress(process_id+"_percentage");
        name = getProgress(process_id+"_process_name");
        message = getProgress(process_id+"_message");
        failed = getProgress(process_id+"_process_failed");

        if(percentage) $(element).find('.progress-bar').css('width',percentage+'%').html(percentage+"% "+message);

    },2000);
}

//initialize progress  bar
//initialize_progress(".progress");

$(".upload-button").click(function()
{


    //set listener
    updateProgress('upload_the_pix', ".progress")


    var request = $.get( "http://example.com/?progress", function(data) {
        alert(data);
    })
        .done(function() {
            alert( "second success" )
        }).fail(function() {
            alert( "error" );
        }).always(function() {
            alert( "finished" );
        });


});
```

HTML

```
 <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Server Side Process  - Using PHP

```
class ProcessProgress
{
    protected static $process_id; //current process_id
    protected static $process_name; //current process name
    protected static $debug_mode = false;
    protected static $process_killed = false;


    /**
     * Make settings for process setup
     * @param $settings
     * Example:
     * $settings=array(
     *   'process_id'    => 'upload_photos' //must be provided
         'process_name'  =>'Database Wipe', //tile of this process
       );
     */
    public static function settings($settings)
    {
        # process id must be set

        #make array keys properties
        if( is_array($settings) ){
            foreach($settings as $key => $value){
                self::$$key = $value;
            }
        }

        if(self::$debug_mode && !self::$process_id) exit('process_id must me provided in settings array');

        if(isset($_COOKIE[self::$process_id."_percentage"])){
            unset($_COOKIE[self::$process_id."_percentage"]);
            unset($_COOKIE[self::$process_id."_message"]);
            unset($_COOKIE[self::$process_id."_process_name"]);
            unset($_COOKIE[self::$process_id."_process_complete"]);
            unset($_COOKIE[self::$process_id."_process_failed"]);
            unset($_COOKIE[self::$process_id."_process_killed"]);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Kill this process
     */
    public static function kill()
    {
        self::$process_killed = true;
    }


    /**
     * @param $percentage
     * @param $message
     * @param bool $complete
     * @param bool $failed
     * @return bool
     */
    public function setProgress($percentage, $message, $complete=false, $failed=false){

        $process_data = array(
            'percentage'=>$percentage,
            'message' => $message,
            'process_id' => self::$process_id,
            'process_name' => self::$process_name,
            'process_complete' => $complete,
            'process_failed' => $failed,
            'process_killed' => self::$process_killed,
        );


        setcookie(self::$process_id."_percentage", $percentage, time() + (86400 * 30)); // 86400 = 1 day
        setcookie(self::$process_id."_message", $message, time() + (86400 * 30)); // 86400 = 1 day
        setcookie(self::$process_id."_process_name", self::$process_name, time() + (86400 * 30)); // 86400 = 1 day
        setcookie(self::$process_id."_process_complete", $complete, time() + (86400 * 30)); // 86400 = 1 day
        setcookie(self::$process_id."_process_failed", $failed, time() + (86400 * 30)); // 86400 = 1 day
        setcookie(self::$process_id."_process_killed", self::$process_killed, time() + (86400 * 30)); // 86400 = 1 day


        //verify
        if(isset($_COOKIE[self::$process_id])) return true;

        #delay 1 second
        //sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Usage on server side when button is click
http://example.com/?progress

```
 if(isset($_GET['progress'])){
ProcessProgress::settings(array(
    'process_id' => 'upload_the_pix',
    'process_name' => 'Picture Upload',
));

ProcessProgress::setProgress(0, 'Initializing');

for($count=0; $count < 10001; $count++){

    switch($count){
        case 1000:
            ProcessProgress::setProgress(10, 'Coping files');
            break;

        case 2000:
            ProcessProgress::setProgress(20, 'Setting up email');
            break;

        case 3000:
            ProcessProgress::setProgress(30, 'Looking up things');
            break;

        case 4000:
            ProcessProgress::setProgress(40, 'Milking your cow');
            break;

        case 5000:
            ProcessProgress::setProgress(50, 'Syncing contacts');
            break;


        case 6000:
            ProcessProgress::setProgress(60, 'Updating Facebook profile');
            break;

        case 7000:
            ProcessProgress::setProgress(70, 'Calling your girl friend');
            break;


        case 8000:
            ProcessProgress::setProgress(80, 'Making things up');
            break;

        case 9000:
            ProcessProgress::setProgress(90, 'Feeding your dogs');
            break;

        case 10000:
            ProcessProgress::setProgress(100, 'Done. Congrats');
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the server/client technology you can go in two directions:

### 1. First with linear processing (this is you current way)

After you move a file on a server from temp send echo to user like "File successfully uploaded. Processing ..." or just in JS you can show message on upload finish event without any info from server or make another ajax call to check..., really, there are many ways for something like that.. point is that after upload server continues file processing (for example OCR 30 pages of just uploaded PDF or whatever) and users have to wait for server to finish processing. 
This smells because if few users are uploading files at the same time everything will be processed at the same time and your server will be at 100% quickly...so this brings me to

### 2. Using job/message queues

After the document is uploaded put file job in queue and inform the user that you will send him an mail (or whatever your way for notifying users is) when processing is completed (something like when you upload document to issuu). This way processing of uploaded files (maybe on another machine ;)) are done one after another and users won't have to wait for file processing to finish... this is preferred way.

For job/message queue you can use:

- [beanstalked](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/)
- [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/),
- something else

Both works with Java, .NET, Ruby, Python, PHP, Perl, C/C++, Erlang, Node.js, what not...

Good luck :)