# Update webpage to show progress while javascript is running in in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I have written javascript that takes 20-30 seconds to process and I want to show the progress by updating the progress bar on my webpage.

I have used setTimeout in an attempt to allow webpage to be re-drawn.

This is how my code looks like:

```
function lengthyFun(...){
   for(...){
      var progress = ...
      document.getElementById('progress-bar').setAttribute('style',"width:{0}%".format(Math.ceil(progress)));

      var x = ...

      // Processing
      setTimeout(function(x) { return function() { ...  }; }(x), 0);
   }
}
```

It does not work, I know why it does not work, but I don't know how to refactor my code to make it work.

Comment: Are you actually processing something on he CLIENT? that is taking 30 seconds?

Comment: _"have written javascript that takes 20-30 seconds to process"_ Can include `html` , `js` at Question ? , create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690326/upload-progress-with-post-processing

Comment: @ppumkin, Yes, I am a beginner, just experimenting with javascript. The webpage is not hosted so there is no server.

Comment: That may be the problem. JavaScript should never run that long! If you are doing an AJAX, you display a loading GIF or a simple progress bar like this. To get the progress bar very accurate, you need to offload the process to the server, implement asynchronous responses that contain the progress percetnage. Using jQuery will help you out allot too.

Comment: @ppumkin Why not ? Javascript is more and more used for powerful (web or not) applications. Using the client to do some long processes can be a way to avoid overloading your server and minimising network overload for example.

Comment: Yea I get that... but you first need to know how to use JavaScript properly.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, the problem here is that you main process (the one that takes a lot of time), is blocking any rendering. That's because JavaScript is (mostly) mono-threaded.

From my point of view, you have two solutions to do this.
The first one is to cut down your main process into different parts and to do the rendering between each of them. I.e. you could have something like that (using Promises) :

```
var processParts = [/* array of func returning promises */];

function start(){
    // call the first process parts
    var firstPartPromise = (processParts.shift())();
    // chain it with all the other process parts interspersed by updateDisplay
    return processParts.reduce(function(prev, current){
        return val.then(current).then(updateDisplay);
    }, firstPartPromise);
}
```

You will probably need a polyfill for the promises ([one here](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise)). If you use jQuery, they have a (bad non standard) implementation.

The second solution can be to use [webworkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) which allows you to create threads in JavaScript. It works on all modern browsers.
It is probably the best solution in your case.
I never used them but you are supposed to be able to do stuff like:

```
var process = new Worker("process.js");

worker.onmessage(function(event){
    updateProgress(event.data.progress)
});
```

And the in `process.js`:

```
postMessage({progress: 0.1});
// stuff
postMessage({progress: 0.4});
// stuff
postMessage({progress: 0.7});
//etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `progress` element attribute `min` to `0` , `max` to `20000` , `value` to `0` ; create function where if `value` less than `max` increment `value` by `1000` ; utilize `setTimeout` with duration set to `1000` to call function recursively until `value` reaches `max`

```js
var p = document.querySelector("progress");

function redraw() {
   if (p.value < p.max) {
     p.value += 1000;
     setTimeout("redraw()", 1000)
   }
}

redraw()
```

```html
<progress max="20000" min="0" value="0"></progress>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways that I know of to trigger sequential HTML redraws through Javascript:

- Incremental Timeout Period
- Recursive Method Calls

The first and easiest way of doing this is by using a multiplier (such as the iterator) on the timeout interval in a loop. This method should be sufficient if the operation is independent of external variables and only needs to be run a finite and relatively few number of times. The more operations required/likely to occur, the greater the strain on resources - just for calculating intervals. Another drawback takes effect when the processing time exceeds the timeout interval, causing a knock-on to the interval of the observed redraws. The result of this can be that the web page freezes up entirely until all operations are done.

Example

```
for (var i=0, limit=n; i<limit; i++) {
    setTimeout((function(params) {
        return  function() {
            some_func(params);
        }
    })(param_values), i*1000);
}
```

The second method is a little more convoluted, but guarantees redraws between each operation, regardless of the timeout interval. Here, the timeout only affects the time between redraws ands resists the effects of consecutive operation variables. However, the processing time for the current operation is still a factor for the observed interval and will still freeze up a web page between redraws if the operation is computationally intensive.

Example

```
var limit = n;
var i = 0;
recursive_timeout();
function recursive_timeout() {
    setTimeout((function(params) {
        return function() {
            some_func(params);
            i++;
            if (i<limit) {
                recursive_timeout();
            }
        }
    })(param_values, i, limit), 1000);
}
```

Refined Example (based off guest271314's answer)

```
var still_true = true;
recursive_timeout();
function recursive_timeout() {
    some_func(params);
    if (still_true) {
        setTimeout(function() {recursive_timeout();}, 1000);
    }
}
```

While the incremental method is fine for simple tasks, recursion will reliably perform redraws. If long processing times per operation is an issue, then it might be worth delving into asynchronous tasks in addition to using recursion in order to avoid rendering a web page temporarily unusable.

Anyway, hope this helps!

Ha! Just realised guest271314 put up a much more elegant example of the recursive method... Oh well, more info can't hurt.