# HTML element updated by JS only after a long function finishes, even if placed before

Tags: javascript, html

The issue is the following: I want to modify a h1 (id="waiting") and then execute a function that takes several seconds to complete (solve).

```
function solveWrapper(table) {
        document.getElementById("waiting").innerHTML = "Wait please, Nurikabe is being solved...";
        alert("alert");
        var currentState = new State(table);
        solve(table, currentState);
    }
```

With this code I get the alert before the solve function is called, but the h1 tag is modified only after that function execution is finished. Does anyone know how to fix this?
This is the button that calls solveWrapper:

```
<button onclick="solveWrapper(grid);">Solve</button>
```

Here is the whole code: https://github.com/jackowski626/projects/blob/master/Nurikabe_SJ_Solver.html

Comment: Put the call to `solve()` in a timeout handler

Comment: @Pointy I placed it in a 5 sec timeout and it does not change anything

Comment: can you add the code you use to call the function (solveWrapper)? Maybe there another function/code that is making the change, in order words, the element is being updated correctly

Comment: You could do it with a **callback** function, or modify your code to return a **Promise**. That ought to solve it. (Or **async await** syntax.)

Comment: @LeonidasMenendez it is called via a html button. That might be the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update webpage to show progress while javascript is running in in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299326/update-webpage-to-show-progress-while-javascript-is-running-in-in-a-loop)

Comment: Or [How to avoid freezing the browser when doing long-running computations in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13546493/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the call to `solve()` in a timeout handler:

```
function solveWrapper(table) {
    document.getElementById("waiting").innerHTML = "Wait please, Nurikabe is being solved...";
    var currentState = new State(table);
    setTimeout(function() {
      solve(table, currentState);
    }, 10);
}
```

Browsers defer updating the view until event loops finish unless they have no choice.

Comment: I tried this:
```
setTimeout(solve(table, currentState), 5000);
```
Why is it wrong?

Comment: @JacekWikiera See [Calling functions with setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3800512/215552)

Comment: When you do it that way, the function is called *before* `setTimeout()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say give this a go:

```
function solveWrapper(table) {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(
    document.getElementById("waiting").innerHTML = "Wait please, Nurikabe is being solved..."
  );
  alert("alert");
  var currentState = new State(table);
  solve(table, currentState);
}
```

The idea is that `requestAnimationFrame` should cause a browser repaint and update what's rendered on the screen for you. I think the issue is that you're calling a change to the innerHTML but it's not being reflected in the browser until it's ready to do it, which is after it runs your solve function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` expects its parameter to be a function. Did you mean to wrap the third line in a function expression?

Comment: yeah, apologies, `window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    document.getElementById("waiting").innerHTML = "Wait please, Nurikabe is being solved..."}
  );`
Although now I'm wondering if you could just wrap it in an immediately invoked function without the `requestAnimationFrame`